# MySQL: how to use comma, single quote, and double quote as columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to pivot a table so I can output the data as a CSV. I need to do something like this:

```
SELECT .... t1.`column_one`, t1.`column_two`, ...
```

Problem is that some of the columns are expected to contain commas, single quotes, and double quotes.

Is there a way to make something like  this work:

```
SELECT .... t1.`foo's, "bar"`, ...
```

The above doesn't work. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tested and can confirm that the following definitely works:

```
SELECT `t1`.`foo's, "bar"` FROM `t1`;
```

The only thing I could suggest is to place the table name between ` (backtick) characters.

Comment: Thanks. It's working now. My SQL looked like what you were suggesting. Not sure why it wasn't working. Thanks again!

Comment: You're right. The backticks (`) are really important and perhaps you mistyped something. Regardless, I'm glad to hear that it's working great for you now!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html) you should be fine as long as the column name is ASCII, doesn't contain an ASCII NUL (`0x00`) and is under 64 characters long in total. What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Does it give an error message?